# Uploading Android bundle files to HockeyApp

Tags: android-build, hockeyapp

Currently we have CI script that uploads APKs to hockeyapp. We basically use hockeyapp to hold all build artifacts. But we are transitioning to using `bundle` format for app distribution. I found out that if one tries to upload `.abb` file that attempt fails. Does anyone know how to upload `android bundle` files to HockeyApp? If not, are there other ways one can maintain archive of bundle files somewhere?

Comment: check https://medium.com/@shinoogoyalaggarwal/upload-app-bundles-or-custom-zip-files-into-hockeyapp-f18ec9e338ba

Answer (score 2):

Hockey app dosn't support AAB files you can still upload APKs to hockyapp and aab files to store.